# Change order of object properties based on array with indices (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, object, key

I've been really struggling with this piece of code.

I have an object that goes like:

```
var obj = {
    Name: 'Test',
    Id: 1,
    Address: 'addr'
}
```

And an array that goes like:

```
var arr = [1,0,2];
```

I want the properties of the object to be sorted with the indices given in the second one.

The result should then be something like:

```
var obj = {
    Id: 1,
    Name: 'Test',
    Address: 'addr'
}
```

I'm really looking forward to your replies.

Comment: Object properties have an ordering that is determined by the runtime. You should absolutely not write code that depends on property ordering, because your code will be subject to weird bugs. Instead, put the property names in an array (or get them with `Object.keys()`) and sort them according to your needs, and then access the object properties via that array.

Comment: Looks like an XY question. What do you mean by "properties of the object to be sorted after the indices"?

Comment: @Pointy Yeah I'm not sure about the sorting though. I will be using the resulting object to fill a .csv file. I'm aware that I can access the keys through Object.keys and then what? How can I use that array I showed to change the order and afterwards assign it back to the object?

Comment: @Phalgun Look at the result object. The properties should have the order of the given indices provided by the array.

Comment: The code shown here is invalid due to the use of special quotes; you must use Unicode U+0022 Quotation Mark character.

Comment: @Neoyaru what you're asking for is not something objects are designed for. They're meant for unordered key/value pairs, not ordered data. The keys do technically have an order, but as pointy said, you should not write code that relies on it. If you'll tell us what you plan to do with your hypothetical ordered object, perhaps we can suggest an alternative way to get there.

Comment: If you really need to re-order try creating a Map from your object.

Comment: @NicholasTower Other code does not rely on the order of the object keys but it will always have to follow a certain order in my use case. I'm trying to export a data grid as a .csv file. I'm looping through the columns and set those as a first line in the csv. Each row has data values that I loop through to print the csv. The problem is that the columns do not always follow the same pattern for each export. That's why I need to change the order of the row values according to the order of the columns made by the user.

Comment: @Neoyaru **you cannot do that.** Make an array with the property names in the order you want, and then access the object properties via the array.

Comment: @Pointy I don't need the keys only, the values need to be altered also.

Comment: OK well that's just not how things work in JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy Okay then this is probably why it's not working.. looks like I have to find a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reliably set the order of the properties in an object. You will need to rethink your approach to this problem so that the order is handled by an array, not an object. The array can then be used to write code that accesses properties in a specific order, even though the object doesn't actually have them in that order.

For example:

```js
const columns = ['Id', 'Name', 'Address'];

const data = [{
  Name: 'Test',
  Id: 1,
  Address: 'addr'
}, {
  Address: 'addr2',
  Id: 1,
  Name: 'Test2',
}];

let csv = columns.join(',') + '\n';
data.forEach(obj => {
  const row = columns.map(propertyName => {
    return obj[propertyName];
  });
  csv = csv + row.join(',') + '\n'
})

console.log(csv);
```